# k2 item.php extra fields Display default image if left blank

Tags: php, joomla3.0, k2

I am currently buiding a site in joomla and using k2 to manage the content
I am creating a template in k2, for item.php. I wish to use an extra field to display a header image on the item.

I have managed to Implement this using the following

**Toward top of document**

```
<?php  
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{    
$extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}   
?>
```

**Positioned where required**

```
      <?php if($extrafields[2]!=''):?> <!-- if filled in, then call data -->
<?php echo $extrafields[2];?> <!-- actual data call -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have succeeded in that If i fill in the extra field i get my header image exactly where i want it, My problem is if i leave the field blank it is meant to revert to a default image, but insted i get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in (URL)\item.php on line 194
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I'm sure I need an or statement but its Friday and my brain is fried. any help much appreciated!

Iameki

---

Thanks to Manuel Dalla Lana, I have implemented your suggestion, but am still receiving the same error. I have implemented it as follows

```
<?php if(isset($extrafields[2]) && $extrafields[2]!=''):?> <!-- if filled in, then call data -->
<?php echo $extrafields[2];?> <!-- actual data call -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please let me know if I have implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: can you post your item.php somewhere like http://codebin.org?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra check on index existence, like this:

```
<?php if(isset($extrafields[2]) && $extrafields[2]!=''):?>
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, Unfortunately I received the same error. I have added my findings to the initial Question.